# Multiple WPF applications in the same AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I got following setup:

WPF_Application.exe

and

a DLL that contains a WinForms Window and an WPF Window.

The 'WPF_Application.exe' calls the WinForms window from the DLL and the WinForms Window creates an instance of the WPF window in the DLL.

That creates following exception:

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

Tried different things, but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed it by asigning the Application of the wpf window that is called to the Application.Current Window:

```
  if (Application.Current == null)
  {
       MyApplication = new Application
       {
          ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
       };
   }
   else
       MyApplication = Application.Current;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To simplify: 
`MyApplication = Application.Current ?? new Application {ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown}`

Comment: It is not clear where this logic goes -- is it in the startup operation - and is MyApplication  just a pointer to the current application launched?

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Application is a singleton: its constructor must only be invoked once (including App.xaml de-xamlization), or exception is thrown.

I'm affraid there is not much you can do about it, except maybe check if Application.Current is set before starting your second application, and somewhat use that instance to load it.

Or you can create another AppDomain, and use it to launch the second application.

Comment: The thing I'm additionally waiting for return value from the winforms app.

Comment: `Application` is not a Singleton. It's a common public class. The fact that the constructor is visible makes that clear. The public constructor can be invoked as often as required. Per definition there is only one instance allowed per `AppDomain`. Multiple instances of `AppDomain` may result in multiple instances of `Application` => no Singleton (shared instance).

Comment: @BionicCode If you call the public constructor more than once, it throws. Call it what you like : I go for singleton. And please instruct me how you can implement a singleton across multiple AppDomains (without using system-wide trickery like named semaphore, etc).

Comment: As I said before, you are only allowed to create one instance **per AppDomain**. The Singleton pattern has a different definition. Singleton would mean one instance per Application. An Application can have multiple AppDomain instances running. There is a difference. Also Singleton is a pattern which also avoids to expose the constructor in order to control instantiation. A Singleton instance is never created explicitly, that's why there is no use for a public constructor. A Singleton instance is static as the instance is exposed via a static class attribute.

Comment: You need to marshal instances or the shared instance across domains: [MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). You would have to extend your Singleton implementation to marshal the shared instance properly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you only have one Application defined in XAML.

Visual studio creates an `App.xaml` when making a new WPF solution, if you have created a new .xaml file with the `<Application></Application>` tag, this will cause this error and the solution will build but fail at runtime.

Delete the duplicate application and use `Window` or `UserControl` to have multiple windows.