# Open WPF prism app from win forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, prism

We're working on a quite large application partly written in Win Forms. From some time we're rewriting some windows to WPF and we're calling it in this way:

```
SomeWindow window = new SomeWindow(someParameters);
window.ShowDialog();
```

Recently we wanted to use PRISM and MahApps in a similar way, but without success.

So I've tried the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = new SomePrism.App();
    app.Run();
}
```

This is starting the app, but if I want to open it again I'll receive following exception:

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

I've tried using answer from [Multiple WPF applications in the same AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586582/multiple-wpf-applications-in-the-same-appdomain) but without success (when I'm trying to open WPF app again, the Application.Current is null, but exception still occurs).

I would also like to 'suspend' the win forms until user is finished working with WPF like it's happening when you show a dialog.

Have someone any idea if this is possible and if it is, how this could be achieved in a proper way?

> EDIT

I've found a solution. Instead of using InitializeShell inside Bootstrapper like below:

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

I've written it in the following way:

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    var window = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: if its a separate application, can you not run it using the ProcessInfo class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working on a dummy app, I will play a bit and see if I can use it on real app, But if someone have other ideas, I'm happy to listen. EDIT: I'll probably need to close my app in a DLL.