# Run a WPF Project from a DLL starting from its App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, mvvm

I have a WPF project that should be able to run independently and can also run as a reference DLL.

I am trying to run the WPF project from another WPF project

Project1 needs to load Project2

Project1 needs to run Project2 as a whole from its App.xaml.cs since this is where DataContexts gets binded. Here is the App.xaml.cs of Project2:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
    Dictionary<Type, Type> viewRegistry = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    viewRegistry.Add(typeof(ImageUploaderViewModel), typeof(ImageUploaderView));
    viewRegistry.Add(typeof(CodBoxViewModel), typeof(CodBoxView));

    Type viewType = viewRegistry[typeof(ImageUploaderViewModel)];

    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");

    Window view = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
    view.DataContext = new ImageUploaderViewModel(viewRegistry);
    view.Show();

    }
}
```

Here is where I try to call the Project 2

```
private void LoadProject2()
{
    string assemblyName = string.Format("{0}\\Project2.dll", new 
    FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName);
    Application app = LoadAssembly(assemblyName, "App");
    app.Run();
}

private Application LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, String typeName)
{
   try
   {
       Assembly assemblyInstance = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
       
       Application app;
       
       foreach (Type t in assemblyInstance.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, typeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
       {
           app = assemblyInstance.CreateInstance(t.FullName) as Application;
           return app;
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0}{1}", assemblyName, ex.Message));
       throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load external window{0}", assemblyName), ex);
   }
}
```

With this I am able to get the Application but I get an error "Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.". I am not sure how to make this possible without having 2 Application instance. Thank you

Comment: Did you see the following answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586582/multiple-wpf-applications-in-the-same-appdomain

Comment: Yes, I have read this but I am not sure how I would implement this on my code the sample codes aren't that clear for me. I want to be able to run both WPF simultaneously.

Comment: You can only have one `Application` instance per `AppDomain`. You would have to [execute your application in a separate `AppDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *start* another app, you should compile the other app and start it in a new process using the `Process.Start` API.

You cannot run two WPF applications in the same process, and it doesn't make any sense to do so either.

If the `DataContexts gets binded` in `App.xaml.cs`, you should probably refactor your code into a separate class library that you can include from any application. Move the code from `OnStartup` into a decopupled method of class in a class library and simply call this method from the `OnStartup` method of the single running application.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping for a different solution but creating a separate class accessible by both the main application and the plugin/standalone application worked for now.